# Swift detect json parsing detect end

Tags: json, swift, swiftui

I am parsing a certain json url data to plot in a map and I need to detect that I have all the data to show a spinner while nothing is happening. I have created a variable that goes from false to true after I have all the data but that variable only exists as true inside the for loop
This is part of the code that gets the data

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

var locationsFillTest : Int = 0
var allLocations = [MKPointAnnotation]()
var doneGettingData : Bool = false

struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    var startdate : String
       
   func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView{
         MKMapView(frame: .zero)
          }
    
   func makeCoordinator() -> MapViewCoordinator{
        MapViewCoordinator(self)
    }
    
   func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context){
    
    uiView.removeAnnotations(allLocations)
    allLocations = []
    doneGettingData = false
    print("Done = \(doneGettingData)")

    let url = URL(string: "https://XXXXXX")!
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data,response,error) in
            do {
                if let d = data {
                    let decodedLists = try JSONDecoder().decode(emsc.self, from: d)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        
                        locationsFillTest = allLocations.count
                        doneGettingData = false
                        
                        for locations in decodedLists.features {
                       
                            
                            let lat = Double(locations.properties.lat)
                            let long = Double(locations.properties.lon)    
                            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                            annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat , longitude: long )
                            if locationsFillTest == 0 {
                                allLocations.append(annotation)}
                        }
                    
                        
                        uiView.addAnnotations(allLocations)
                        uiView.delegate = context.coordinator
                        uiView.showAnnotations(allLocations, animated: true)
                        doneGettingData = true
                        print("Done = \(doneGettingData)")
                      
                    }
                    
                }else {
                    print("No Data")
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error decoding JSON: ", error, response!)
            }
            
        }.resume()
    
    }
    
}
```

The variable doneGettingData becomes false and true by watching the print but if I need to use it for example to create a spinner its false all the time since its only true inside.
How can I make it global ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have another declaration for `doneGettingData` inside the closure the instance level property is getting set to true. It may be getting set later than you expect though. Try the following to see when it changes (and to get you setup to react to those changes):

```
var doneGettingData : Bool = false {
    didSet {
        if doneGettingData {
            print("The instance property doneGettingData is now true.")
        } else {
            print("The instance property doneGettingData is now false.")
        }
    }
}
```

You may want to make this into a custom enum though with cases along the lines of `fetching`, `done`, `noData`, and `jsonError`. Right now if there is no data you will never have a trigger to either retry, move on, notify the user, etc. The same applies when there is a decoding error. Or at the very least set the flag to true at the very end of the loop so something happens no matter what.

Something like:

```
enum DataCollectionState {
    case fetching, done, noData, jsonError
```

```
var doneGettingData : DataCollectionState = fetching {
    didSet {
        switch doneGettingData {
            case fetching:
                // Show a spinner or something
            case done:
                // Hide the spinner
            case noData:
                // Tell the user there was no data? Try again?
            case jsonError:
                // Tell the user there was an error? Try again?
        }
    }
}
```

*Note: I don't have Xcode open right now so syntax may not be exact.*

Comment: Thank you - if I use your suggestion it does change, so actually the variable its changing, but  in ContentView ( SwiftUI)  just for testing if I do this  : Text(doneGettingData.description) its false than it changes to true and never changes back to false and true again when I change for example one of the parameters that forces to get a new Json.